# Algolia Rails : Cannot reach any host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, algolia

I've changed my `Rails.application.config.session_store` key to a new one to force all my devise users to reconnect.

The side effect of this is that now I'm unable to connect to Algolia somehow, even if I create a brand new application in Algolia with new index and new API key.

I've searched the error on the issue and code of [the github repo](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails) without success.

Here is the error:

```
[algoliasearch-rails] Cannot reach any host:
Connection refused - connect(2) for "MY_APP_ID-dsn.algolia.net" port 443 (https://MY_APP_ID-dsn.algolia.net:443),
Connection refused - connect(2) for "MY_APP_ID-3.algolianet.com" port 443 (https://MY_APP_ID-3.algolianet.com:443),
Connection refused - connect(2) for "MY_APP_ID-1.algolianet.com" port 443 (https://MY_APP_ID-1.algolianet.com:443),
Connection refused - connect(2) for "MY_APP_ID-2.algolianet.com" port 443 (https://MY_APP_ID-2.algolianet.com:443)
```

Any idea what might be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours the problem was gone. Maybe some kind of DNS propagation or something...

Comment: Yes most probably that, I've experienced it a few times while using a newly created account.